# Sound devices MixPre-D

Tags: sound-devices, audio-interfaces, field-recording, pre-amp

I have read couple of post talking about this pre, and everybody seems to be pretty happy with the job out there. But what I would really like to know is how it works as a Audio interfece, has anybody any experience? I am using Mac and ProTools 9. I would use it has main interface until I can buy a RME. 
Are the converters good? As I said I have read a lot how good it is on the field but I would like to know if I can realy on it in the studio.

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I can tell you that the headphone amp doesn't sound half bad, and it has been working well for me. I don't have much to compare to though. If you want to use it as an interface, you pretty much have to buy the ~$80 dollar power supply or else you're running on batteries forever.

Comment: Hello, thank you. Which DAW are you using? solid dirvers? I could take the headhone signal and put it into my little mixer and then to the Speakers no? Is it a specific power supply from SD?
Thanks again!

Comment: I run Pro Tools 10 on mac. Yeah, there is also a mini line out and xlr line out, but I haven't tried either for monitoring. Sound devices does sell a specific power supply, I don't think there are alternatives. As for drivers, do you mean software? It was plug and play for me.

Comment: Ohh okay. So you are pleased with the results as a interface audio eh?Plug and play is cool, nice. Yeah the dirver things it was if pro tools and SD went well together. I will look for the power supply.
Thank you